# Decoupling Vue.js Web Application from electron's ipcRender for Browser Compatibility

Tags: electron, vuejs3

I am developing a web application using Vue 3.js, and currently, some features of my application rely on [Electron's ipcRender](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) module. However, I want to completely decouple my application from ipcRender to ensure browser compatibility and the ability to run the application independently of Electron.

One idea I have is to use conditional compilation to include or exclude the ipcRender functionality based on the target environment. This approach would allow me to have separate code paths for Electron and browser environments. However, I would like to know if there are any better patterns or recommended practices to solve this problem.

**Conditional compilation example:**

```
sendMessage(message) {
  if (process.env.IS_ELECTRON) {
    // Electron environment
    const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron')
    ipcRenderer.send('message', message)
  } else {
    // Browser environment
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Regards